# Show $||U_i-V_i||\leq\epsilon\ \ \forall i=1,...,m\Longrightarrow||U_m...U_1-V_m...V_1||\leq m\epsilon$ (spectral norm)

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, spectral-norm

Let $\{U_i\},\{V_i\}$ be sets of $m$ unitary operators with $||U_i-V_i||\leq\epsilon\ \ \forall i=1,...,m$.

Then $||U_m...U_1-V_m...V_1||\leq m\epsilon$ with $||\cdot||$ being the spectral norm.

Can someone help me show this conclusion? I'm going through some lecture notes and they omit the proof because it is "easy."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{split}
||U_m...U_1-V_m...V_1|| &= \left \| \sum_{i=1}^m U_m...U_iV_{i-1}...V_1-U_m...U_{i+1}V_i...V_1 \right\|\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^m \|U_m...U_iV_{i-1}...V_1-U_m...U_{i+1}V_i...V_1\| \\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^m \| U_m...U_{i+1}(U_i-V_i)V_{i-1}...V_1\|\\
&\leq \sum_{i=1}^m \|U_m...U_{i+1}\|\|U_i-V_i\|\|V_{i-1}...V_1\|\\
\end{split}$$
where the last inequality comes from the fact that with the spectral norm, $\|AB\|\leq\|A\|\|B\|$.
Also, any unitary transform $T$ has spectral norm $1$, so
$\|U_m...U_{i+1}\|=\|V_{i-1}...V_1\|=1$.

Finally, one can conclude that
$$||U_m...U_1-V_m...V_1|| 
\leq \sum_{i=1}^m \| U_i-V_i\|\leq m\varepsilon
$$

Comment: Fantastic! I'd never seen that first step (the equality) done before!